# Registry key location that multiple non-admin users can read and write under different users?

Tags: permissions, registry, regedit, registrykey

Is there a registry key location in which multiple **NON-admin** users can read and **write** ?

I need to write a registry-key as non-admin user in a web-application, that another non-admin user needs to read in his web-applicaton.

So far, in HKLM/SOME_PATH, both users can read, but the one that needs to write cannot write. 
And in HKCU/SOME_PATH, one user can write, but the other cannot read it.

Something like

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

except with registry instead of files.

Note:
With a windows-system as-is.
**Without** somebody having to set read/write rights in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HKLM ain't writable for basic-users. Most of subkeys ain't even readable.

HKCU, as its name indicate, is only accessible in the context of the current user.

So :

> Is there a registry key location in which multiple NON-admin users can
>   read and write ?

Registry 'd better be protected !

> Without somebody having to set read/write rights...

No

> ... in advance

Depends. Since the owner basically have all the rights on the key, just make him manage the rights for the users group at the creation of keys (or even, change the owner of the keys since this last one automatically have free_access on it).

However, it can't be done in a basic-user context which seems to be your case ?